# How get access to mounted usb drive on a Remmina remote windows 10 desktop

Tags: 18.04, usb, mount, windows-10, remote-desktop

I need access to the USB ports on the host Ubuntu 18.04 computer which successfully connects to a remote Windows 10 desktop via Remmina. Everything works well including clipboard and folder sharing.

I'm currently trying to get access the USB port in Windows. I have tried playing with around the advanced settings (see image attached) to no avail.

How can I plug in a USB device and get access to this device natively on the remote Windows session? Thanks in advance.

[image: Current Remmina Desktop Advanced Settings]

Comment: Remmina is a screen sharing option. AFAIK If the host is not looking at the device there would be no way of doing so on the client.

Comment: @Graham that's a shame. Any way around this?

Comment: Is the USB on the Windows machine? If so, this could be off topic here because the question is not about Ubuntu but rather Windows.

Comment: @Graham the usb is on the Ubuntu host

Answer (score 1):

in remmina 1.4.8 (I use the snap package) there is an option to bind USB devices called 'USB device redirection' under the Advanced tab of the connection. Still a bit hardwork to find out what and how to bind as there's only a tooltip explaining only a few things.

Pointed out here: https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2049